# How to add a button over an ImageView in ScrollView dynamically? Android. Xamarin

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, imageview, scrollview

I have an axml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mylinearlayout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
    android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:layout_width="1dip" />
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/filesScrollerLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</ScrollView>
<VideoView
    android:layout_width="1dip"
    android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:id="@+id/videoView1" />
```

My application takes a photo and video and puts it in the LinearLayout.

When I add video, I create an ImageView dynamically, put the firstframe of the video in this ImageView and add it in LinearLayout.

```
private void addBitmapToLayout(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
    iv.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
    linearlayout.AddView(iv);
}
```

How can I put a button over this ImageView in LinearLayuot dynamically to start the video?
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtXAO.png)
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding an `ImageView` to your `LinearLayout`, add a custom layout where you'll have your `ImageView` as well as a `Button` on top

Define the layout for each item in your list :

```
<RelativeLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/imageView"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
<Button
  android:id="@+id/button"
  android:layout_centerInParent="true"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Your function now becomes :

```
private void addBitmapToLayout(Bitmap bitmap) {
  LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
  RelativeLayout layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null, false);
  ImageView iv = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
  iv.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);

  //Add click listener to your Button etc...
  Button button = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.button);

  linearlayout.AddView(layout);
}
```